# Program hangs and does not loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, codeblocks

I am a beginner in c++. I wrote a program to separate the digits in an integer entered and display them and their sum. However, when the loop repeats, the program hangs even though it compiled perfectly. I tried a '... while' loop and a while loop but the problem persists. What should I do to have it repeat (ask user for next integer, calculate and display the results) without problems? Any help will be appreciated.

```
//Preprocessor directives
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

//Standard library
using namespace std;

//enter function main
int main()
{
int num;
int digit;
int sum = 0;
int pwr = 0;



cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
cin >> num;
cout << endl;
 while (num != 0 )
 {
//while loop to ask user to enter another number
cout << "The integer you entered is: " << num << endl;
cout << "The digits of " << num << " are: " << endl;

if (num < 0)
    num = -num;

    //find the highest number of 10 that divides the number

while (num / static_cast<int>(pow(10.0, pwr)) >= 10)
    pwr++;

while (num > 0)
{
    digit = num / static_cast<int>(pow(10.0, pwr));
    cout << digit << " ";
    sum = sum + digit;
    num = num % static_cast<int>(pow(10.0, pwr));
    pwr--;
}

if (pwr != -1) //Either num is 0 or there are trailing zeros in num
    while (pwr != -1)
    {
        cout << 0 << " ";
        pwr--;
    }
cout << endl;

cout << "The sum of the digits = " << sum << endl;

while (num != 0);
cout << "Enter another integer: " << endl;
cin >> num;
cout << endl;


}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Knowing this is a skill you *need* if you want to be serious about programming, even if it's "only" as a hobby.

Comment: As a hint though, what do you think `while (num != 0);` does?

Comment: You shouldn't use `pow` for this. Mixing floating point into an integer problem is an invitation to mayhem.

Comment: Do you know how to change an int value to a string? That will make the display-each-digit portion easier, and I will recommend a single for loop instead of the while()'s. Pseudocode it instead of jumping onto the keyboard. Convert the number to a string, or, alternately, cin a string, display the individual characters of the string within the for loop, then convert each digit to an int an add to an accumulator (still within the for loop). At the end of the display-each-digits, display the accumulated total. But you really do need to practice this. This cod of yours is WAAAAAY overkill!

Comment: Well I think that while (num !=0) executes the statements following it when the expression in the bracket is true. Hence if num does not equal 0 is true, the statements execute. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Preprocessor directives
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

//Standard library
using namespace std;

//enter function main
int main()
{

 while (true )
 {
//reset initial values every loop
int num;
int digit;
int sum = 0;
int pwr = 0;

cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
cin >> num;
cout << endl;
//same exit condition
if (num == 0)
    break;
//while loop to ask user to enter another number
cout << "The integer you entered is: " << num << endl;
cout << "The digits of " << num << " are: " << endl;

if (num < 0)
    num = -num;

    //find the highest number of 10 that divides the number

while (num / static_cast<int>(pow(10.0, pwr)) >= 10)
    pwr++;

while (num > 0)
{
    digit = num / static_cast<int>(pow(10.0, pwr));
    cout << digit << " ";
    sum = sum + digit;
    num = num % static_cast<int>(pow(10.0, pwr));
    pwr--;
}

if (pwr != -1) //Either num is 0 or there are trailing zeros in num
    while (pwr != -1)
    {
        cout << 0 << " ";
        pwr--;
    }
cout << endl;

cout << "The sum of the digits = " << sum << endl;
//extraneous
/*while (num != 0);
cout << "Enter another integer: " << endl;
cin >> num;
cout << endl;*/


}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love this answer. Thank you. I assume the principle change is the declarations and initializing are inside the while loop?

Comment: @HamzaKamran yeah, its good practice to initialize variables in the scope they're used in. In this case, when you initialize them at the start of every iteration, you're ensuring the values from the last loop are reset, and the output values are correct. Also, moving the cin statement inside of the while loop helps shorten the code, and is basically equivalent to "continually ask for integer input and calculate sum of individual integers so long as the input doesn't equal zero, and if so exit".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use vector to store the digits... also the logic inside should be a bit smaller (see note 1), (note that I didn't test for negatives, you may use abs from cmath)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//Standard library
using namespace std;

//enter function main
int main()
{
    int num;
    std::vector<int> digits;
    int sum = 0;
    int pwr = 0;

    cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    while (num) {
        while (num) {
            int temp = num % 10;
            digits.push_back(temp);
            sum += temp;
            num /= 10;
        }
        std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end());
        cout << sum << endl;
        for(auto & a : digits)
        {
            cout << a << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter another integer: " << endl;
        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

note 1:

```
    while (num) {
        int temp = num % 10;
        sum += temp;
        num /= 10;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That will help, however that is probably too advanced for my professor's preferences since she hasn't covered it

Comment: you can use arrays, right? use a new variable to save the position from where to start in the array, and display numbers in order... I assume longest possible value will be from the int (2147483647)
modify the code in the following way: and you will have the same functionality

https://godbolt.org/g/6xVN1R